# Sending user-name/password instead of security tokens issues

Tags: security, https

Is there any risk to use clear user-name/password instead of security tokens in the api post body to authenticate requests? knowing that requests are secure using https, and all requests are of type POST.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to do this for every request (similar to HTTP Basic authentication) then you are increasing the chance for attackers to exploit other vulnerabilities in the communication system (weak ciphers, bad certificates, etc.) - for HTTP Basic weaknesses check https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/988/is-basic-auth-secure-if-done-over-https.

Moreover, if it's possible to use a special-purpose token you should prefer that because they usually:

- have a smaller set of permissions
- can be easily revoked without having to change your password.
- can be single-purpose (e.g. just for the api access by application XYZ)